# com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "beer-sample" do not match

Tags: scala, apache-spark, authentication, couchbase, connector

I am connecting the Couch base with Scala through the scala shell.
However, the following error occurs.
(Spark: 2.2v, couchbase: 5.0.1v, spark-couchbase-connector: 2.2v)

My code

```
$ bin/spark-shell --packages com.couchbase.client:spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0 --conf "spark.couchbase.bucket.beer-sample=" 

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
scala> import com.couchbase.spark.sql._
scala> val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Myapp").master("local[*]").config("spark.couchbase.nodes", "127.0.0.1").config("spark.couchbase.bucket.beer-sample", "").config("com.couchbase.username","beer-sample").config("com.couchbase.password","beer17**").getOrCreate()
scala> val dataFrame = spark.read.couchbase()
```

error

```
18/06/26 16:40:38 WARN Endpoint: [null][KeyValueEndpoint]: Authentication Failure.
    Caused by: com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "beer-sample" do not match.
```

I created the username the same as the bucket name, and added the user authentication code. I do not know why the error occurred.

Help me please.

Comment: Have you tried passing all those params already when loading the spark shell? Also to double check try connecting via the java sdk with those credentials directly to the bucket and see if you still get the error.